# Пропадает сеть

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2, сеть, debian

Доброго времени суток.

Творится невообразимая штука какая-то.Установил себе `Debian` на сервак, поставил Апач, `Mysql`, `phpmyadmin`.

В `apache2.conf` прописал инклюд конфига для апача в `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

Открываю страницу с `phpmyadmin` и пропадает сеть. Непонятно, что твоится. Было ли у кого-то нечто похожее?

P.S. Даже веник уже заменил, толку - ноль.

Comment: > и пропадает сетьВот с этого места по подробнее, ping пропал, сетевую в ifconfig невидно, vpn отвалился или просто apache перестал отвечать?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась :) Это Ядро устаревшее с новым железом не поладило. Обновил ядрышко, заработало как часы :D Если честно, так и не понял чо за прикол )

А пропадала сеть... именно сеть. Единственное что не отвалилось - это пинг до 127.0.0.1До внешнего сетевого адреса (10.1.1.4) пинг тоже пропал ( это IP eth0), хотя интерфейс был активен (судя по состоянию)

Comment: Рад за Вас.